# 404 error in Custom Magento configuration in admin

Tags: magento, adminhtml

I'm developing a custom SMS module in Magento 1.6.

I've setup the `system.xml` file to manage the related custom configuration fields.

The menu entry shows up, but when I click it, a 404 error page is shown instead of the expected configuration fields list.

Can you see any errors in my code?

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <mynew_tab translate="label">
        <label>SMS Gateway Integration</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </mynew_tab>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <smsconfig  translate="label">
        <label>SMS Gateway Integration</label>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <tab>mynew_tab</tab>
        <groups>
            <sms_group translate="label">
                <label>My Custom Configurations</label>
                <comment>This is example of custom configuration.</comment>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <sms_enabled translate="label tooltip comment">
                        <label>Is Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Enable this module.</comment>
                    </sms_enabled>
                    <sms_username translate="label tooltip comment">
                        <label>Sender Email</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Username of the SMS gateway.</comment>
                    </sms_username>
                    <sms_password translate="label tooltip comment">
                        <label>Sender Email</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Password of the SMS gateway.</comment>
                    </sms_password>
                </fields>
            </sms_group>
        </groups>
    </smsconfig>
</sections>
```

After ben's request, we placed the adminhtml.xml file. I placed the content of the XML file.

```
<config>
<acl>   
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <sms translate="title" module="sms">
                                    <title>SMS Gateway Section</title>
                                </sms>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
           </children>
       </admin>
   </resources>
</acl>
```

But till the 404 error comes...

Comment: To find the exact error: This Worked for me http://pradhab.blogspot.com/2013/03/magento-404-error.html Try this

Comment: Please don't supply "link only" answers (what will happen if the page on the remote site is taken down?). If the external content is relevant, add the steps / code to your answer and you can cite the source as an extra note.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A 404 error in system configuration often means that there is an issue with ACL. You are likely missing the appropriate acl node in your module's `adminhtml.xml` file:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <smsconfig> <!-- translate="title" module="sms_config" if appropriate and depending on config -->
                                    <title>Your Section</title>
</...>
```

After adding the above you will need to log out and log back in for full admin role users and explicitly add this role to custom admin user roles.

Comment: I placed the adminhtml.xml file and follow your instruction. But till it though 404 error.

Comment: You are correct Ben, I have some bugs in my code. Now it was working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to disconnect to take effect.

Comment: `<sms_config>` should be `<smsconfig>`, same as the name used in system.xml under `sections`

Comment: Indeed it should. Edited.

Comment: Had same problem. Configuration was OK, just forgot to log out and log back. Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 3):

Do what @benmarks said plus be sure to add the right children (in your case) `smsconfig`

(@benmarks used `sms_config` instead of `smsconfig`)

```
<!-- namespace/modulename/etc/adminhtml.xml -->
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <smsconfig> <!-- translate="title" module="sms_config" if appropriate and depending on config -->
                                    <title>Your Section</title>
</...>
```

clear cache, admin logout, admin login == works

**Hint**: If you get 404 look at the url (when you clicked on your tab):

`/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/mymodulename_something/...`

This url *seems* to *point* to `mymodulename_something`:

```
<!-- namespace/modulename/etc/system.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <mymodulename translate="label" module="mymodulename">
            <label>MyModuleName Awesome Label</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </mymodulename>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <mymodulename_something translate="label" module="mymodulename">
<!-- ... -->
```

so your **adminhtml.xml** would look like:

```
<!-- namespace/modulename/etc/adminhtml.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mymodulename_something translate="title" module="mymodulename">
                                        <title>have no idea where this is showing up btw</title>
                                    </mymodulename_something>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't underestimate the need to log out and then log back in after making ACL changes. Even if you clear your cache, you will still 404 until you log out and log back in.